# Customize Chosen plugin button

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

The jquery plugin https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ has a down arrow button that I can not access. 
[image: Chosen Button]

It's included by a `<div> <b> </ b> </ div>` but I do not know how to change that, I'd like to include an icon, put a class in that div.

I would like to modify this button to look like this:
[Button Demo CSS](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Radio-Button-Based-Dropdown-Select-with-jQuery-CSS3-Dropp/)
[image: Button]

But without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This arrow is included in a background sprite image. You can use the web inspector of your browser to see the corresponding CSS:

```
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(chosen-sprite.png) no-repeat 0px 2px;
}
```

Replace the `chosen-sprite.png` with your own image to replace the arrow. You can also set `background: none;` and use the pseudo element `::after` to create your custom arrow.

Here is an example with the pseudo element approach. Of course you have to adjust the styles to your needs:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chosen").chosen();
});
```

```css
.chosen+.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: none;
}

.chosen+.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
  color: orange;
}
.chosen+.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b::after {
  content: '∨';
}
.chosen+.chosen-container-single.chosen-with-drop .chosen-single div b::after {
  content: '∧';
}


/* the following styles are for demonstration purposes */
html,
body {
  background: black;
}
.chosen + .chosen-container-single .chosen-single {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: black;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- single dropdown -->
<select class="chosen" style="width:200px;">
  <option>Choose...</option>
  <option>jQuery</option>
  <option selected="selected">MooTools</option>
  <option>Prototype</option>
  <option>Dojo Toolkit</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I made some changes and I got the result

Answer (score 0):

This is the css code for the button that you want:

```
.down-icon {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.down-icon:before,
.down-icon:after {
   top: 30%;
   left: 25%;
   width: 50%;
   height: 15%;
   background: #dd4040;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
   transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.down-icon:after {
   top: 55%;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer from @andreas https://stackoverflow.com/a/51615919/7840206 I made some modifications and got the result I was looking for

```
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.5em;
    height: 1.5em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: none;

}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b:before,
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b:before,
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b:after {
   top: 30%;
  left: 25%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 15%;
  background: #dd4040;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single div b:after{
  top: 55%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```